# Javascript loop hangs

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

Okay, I'm getting out of options here.

I'm trying to execute this code, but it hangs always. I've already tried modify the "for" loop with a "while" loop, no results at all, also tried to make it a function and execute it by the setTimeout() with as usual, no luck at all. I don't know what else to do.

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function() {
    for( var i=1; i<50; i++ ) {
        var theurl = 'include_test.php?appid=' + i;
        $('#index').html(i);
        $.get(theurl, function(response) {
            var checking = response.split(" - ");
            if(checking.length > 1) {
                $('#main').append(response);
                $('#index').html(checking[0]);
            } else {
                $('#index').html(response);
            }
        });
    }
}); 
</script>
```

What am I missing here?

ADDED

By "hangs" I mean the tab stop responding and crashes. Also, if I remove the ajax requests, code still doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
    for(i=1;i<50;i++){
        $('#index').text(i);
    }
});
```

ADDED

Here's the HTML with the comment. Don't know why, but when I removed them, the code started working :/

```
<body>
<!-- result index -->
<div id="index"></div>
<!-- result content -->
<div id="main"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

After managed to get it working removing a comment (yes, a comment) I found another... "bug"? I don't know what's wrong with me and JS.

To see the "bug" reffer to the testing webpage [HERE](http://www.2gamers.com.ar/scripting/)
Is there any reason why the loop works unordened? Is there any way to make it work in order?

Comment: What do you mean 'hangs' ?

Comment: I'm guessing 50 ajax calls at the same time wasn't such a good idea ?

Comment: Are you doing 50 get request?

Comment: no matther what, it hangs, tab not responding, also tried to remove the ajax requests, same result...
$(document).ready(function() {
 var i = 0;
 for(i=1;i<50;i++){
  $('#index').text(i);
 }
});

Comment: you should use a success event-handler in which you trigger the next round

Comment: for me it works http://jsfiddle.net/vNExf/

Comment: Have you included jQuery?

Comment: Any reason that you can't send the 50 ids at once a.k.a make one request instead of 50?

Comment: @user3153340 Glad you have made progress. If you pasted some of your html it might help diagnose why removing the comment made a difference!

Comment: Do you see any errors in browser console? If so please post them. Pretty sure the jquery code you are using might not be culprit if there is no ajax call in it.

Comment: I don't "need it" I just want it. The include_test.php file make a db query, send data to a remote db and performs a curl execution sending post data to a remote server, I want to watch the result of each ID separatedly while doing it (the real final number of queries will be around 380k)

Answer (score 1):

Add a fail function to your code and tell us what happens.
Example of using the jquery fail function-

http://jsfiddle.net/hbh3a/

documentation of the fail function
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

in your code it would be something like this:

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function() {
for( var i=1; i<50; i++ ) {
    var theurl = 'include_test.php?appid=' + i;
    $('#index').html(i);
    $.get(theurl, function(response) {
        var checking = response.split(" - ");
        if(checking.length > 1) {
            $('#main').append(response);
            $('#index').html(checking[0]);
        } else {
            $('#index').html(response);
        }
    })
    .fail(function(){//put failure code here console.log('failure');
   });
}
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: He said that even when he removes the AJAX call, it still hangs. And if the AJAX call successfully fails, then there wasn't a hang.

Comment: Impossible. The loop he provided without the ajax works fine in JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/M96KV/. It would be something unrelated completely to this piece of code then.

Comment: done, it was a comment on the html, dunno why, but when I removed it, the code started working. now I've encountered another "bug" u.u I'm getting tired of JS.

Comment: Which is what I wanted to find out with the fail. If it returns anything then the hang is probably elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Making 50 AJAX calls at once is not a good idea, in general. The reason that they come back not in order is because you aren't calling them in order, you're calling them all at once, so they come back in the order of whichever finishes first. You could chain them one after another, but you're better off doing almost all of this in PHP by making 10 curls at once, and then sending back all 10 once they're finished, and doing that 5 times.

Comment: What do you mean "with 380k"? Is that the load of the AJAX call? That's actually not that large. What exactly is your goal here? I know it's something with Steam game IDs.

Comment: 380K = 380.000 requests. I'm testing the script with steam because it's kinda easy for me to try with it first, then I'll be moving to the real deal, and the script need to do at least 380.000 ajax requests per day, That's why I was wondering if there is any way to sort it, or sort the results, with 50 you can do a lot of stuff, but with 380k, it get's more complicated.